# Select count, group by query is not picking records for NULL and Empty String Column Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, how could I get count, group by for a column either it has values or NULL or empty?

This query is not returning NULL and Empty String values. It returns only if `BillType` has some values on it.

```
select count(BillType), BillType 
from Bills
group by BillType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
Select BillType
     ,count(*)
From  Bills
Group by BillType
```

Comment: Thank you John, Yes it works.I have included the Sample Query for testing purpose.

Comment: @goofyui the sample data was a nice touch, but I was pretty confident on this  one :)

Comment: Yes, you are. I was so thankful for your patindex help also. Including sample will be helpful for everyone

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you are `Count`-ing the Bill type, not the rows. First try this:

```
Select BillType, count(*)
From Bills
Group By BillType
```

but if that doesn't work (I've no access to SQL Server), this will for sure...

```
Select coalesce(BillType, 'Null'), count(*)
From Bills
Group By coalesce(BillType, 'Null')
```